Am i using the scanf function properly
I am writing code using Scanf and i want it to take in three different inputs at once perform some computations using those inputs and give me an output but it is not working as i expected .
Firstly it is only taking one function and is also displaying the values next to where the inputs are going that is the 100s, 200s, and 500s which you will see please help me with some clarity.
The code is;
# include<stdio.h>
int main () {
    //input
    double a=100,b=200,c=500;
    int d,e,f;
    printf("Please enter the number of coins you have for each denomination below\n");
    printf("If you have no coins in that denomination input zero.\n");
    scanf("100s:%lf",&d);
    scanf("200s;%lf",&e);
    scanf("500s:%lf",&f);
    //computation
    double g=(double)((a*d)+(b*e)+(c*f));
    //output
    printf("Change is shs:%lf",g);
}

I was expecting my terminal to display the following:
100s:
200s:
500s:
then
Change is shs:
But it is not

(1) With scanf - %lf is for doubles, not ints, %d is for ints, (2) Always check the return value from scanf (it will be the number of fields successfuly assigned).

scanf doesn't print things.

Also if you want to print 100s etc. use printf. scanf does not output anything, only expects input in the specified format.

Everything in the scanf format string describes the expected input -- you don't put the prompt there.

FYI you don't need the (double) cast. The value is already double because you're multiplying double * int.

If you use scanf("100s:%lf",&d);, then scanf will try to read and discard 100s: in the user input. If it does not find it, it will just return 0 to indicate a matching failure and not do anything else. In particular, it won't write anyting to d. Since you probably want to print 100s: instead, I suggest that you change scanf("100s:%lf",&d); to printf("100s: "); scanf("%d", &d);.

You can write double g=(double)((a*d)+(b*e)+(c*f)); simply as double g=a*d+b*e+c*f;

If you want a function that combines output and input so that the text prompt is printed as part of the input function, then you will have to make your own function which does that. You could for example make a function that calls printf and scanf. However, using scanf is generally not recommended for user input. See my function get_int_from_user from this answer of mine to another question which does what you want, but does not use scanf. This answer also explains why not to use scanf.

@AndreasWenzel you may need a flush in there too if there's no newline.

scanf() wasn't designed for user input. Ask your teacher to teach you about fgets() and use that in the future.

There is also a typo in "200s;%lf" with the ';'. Note that scanf() must match every character in the format string to the input. The format is precise: every character has a specific meaning. With this format string you are expected to enter "200s;" followed by a double value.

"Am i using the scanf function properly?" - Answer No. You cannot use any input function correctly unless you check the return to determine whether input succeeded or failed. Particularly with scanf() you must check the return to protect against an input or matching failure. Failure to check the return and just blindly assuming input succeeds is a recipe for invoking Undefined Behavior when an error goes undetected.


I was expecting my terminal to display the following:
100s:
200s:
500s:

Evidently, then, you were expecting scanf() to produce output to the terminal (100s:, 200s:, 500s:) before reading input.  scanf does not do that. It is an input function only.  If you want to print prompts, then use an output function such as printf.
Additionally, the pointers you provide for storing converted input must be type-matched to the conversion specifiers in your format. %lf should be matched with a pointer to double, but you are matching it with pointers to int.  If you want to input signed integers then use specifier %d. If you want to input decimal floating point numbers then switch the types of your variables to double.
For example,
double d, e, f;

// ...

printf("100s:");
fflush(stdout);  // flush the output buffer so the prompt is shown right away
scanf("%lf",&d);

Furthermore, you may want to add a \n to the end of the format for the last printf().  Otherwise, there won't be a newline between the end of the program's output and the next shell prompt.

Hmm, I thought scanf() on stdin caused  a flush on stdout.  I'll have to research that.

@chux-ReinstateMonica, I think there may be C implementations that exhibit such behavior, but I don't find any support for it in the language spec.  On the contrary, the spec says "The scanf function is equivalent to fscanf with the argument stdin interposed before the arguments to scanf" (C2X, 7.23.6.4/2), which does not seem consistent with a scanf-specific flush, and I find nothing in the specs for fscanf about special-case behavior for stdin.  Plus, we fairly frequently get questions about exactly the problem of stdout not being flushed before stdin is read.

@chux: The C11 standard states in §7.21.3 ¶3: "Furthermore, characters are intended to be transmitted as a block to the host environment [...] when input is requested on an unbuffered stream, or when input is requested on a line buffered stream that requires the transmission of characters from the host environment. Support for these characteristics is implementation-defined [...]" -- Therefore, as far as I can tell, the C standard recommends, but does not require this.

I too recall the statement that invoking and input function causes associated output streams to be flushed, but that was likely from a man-page and implementation specific. The standard leaves it to the implementation. But like most "unicorn" features, I've yet to find an implementation that doesn't flush fputs ("...", stdout) (with no '\n') followed by scanf (...), but according to the standard it would be perfectly okay if fflush(stdout) was required in between.

@DavidC.Rankin et al.  So much about flushing is implementation-defined, so yes, fflush(stdout) is wise.
